# Running Compiled Java classes from batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to package a Java application so it can be run from a batch file, I am using a JRE in the directory, my current batch file (run.bat) looks like this:

```
.\program\jre8\bin\java.exe -cp ..\ mainUI
pause
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
Folder
    /program
        /jre8
            ...JRE in here...
        mainUI.class
        ...Other Classes in Here...
    run.bat
```

When this runs it says it can't find the mainUI class, can anyone help diagnose this?

Thanks,
Harris Mirza

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath is not in "../" but in "./program" , according to the directory structure given. Try `.\program\jre8\bin\java.exe -cp ./program/* mainUI`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this still seems to give the same error.

Comment: if you cd inside the program directory and try 'java mainUI' on the command line, what does happen then? - if this works, then your description of the dir-stucuture in the above post is most likely wrong.

Comment: This also doesn't work, do you have to use the package name when running classes?

Comment: The folder structure must match the package structure.

Comment: All my classes are in a package named F454, I have moved them to a folder called F454 in the program Directory but it still hasn't worked.

Comment: what exactly "doesn't work" when you try to run th program from the command-line as stated in my last comment?

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath is relative to your working directory (which is the directory your batch file resides in when double clicking it). You should change it to `java -cp program mainUI` as your run.bat seems to sit above your program folder.

As you use packages please try

F454/mainUI.java

```
package F454;

public class mainUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

run.bat

```
jre\bin\java.exe -cp . F454.mainUI
pause
```

and this structure

```
/program
    /jre
    /F454
        mainUI.class
    run.bat
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, it still says that the class cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, I have now solved the problem.
My batch file looks like this:

```
cd ./program/F454FinalProject
..\jre8\bin\java.exe F454.mainUI
pause
```

And my file structure is like this:

```
Folder
    /program
        /jre8
            ...JRE in here...
        /F454FinalProject
            /F454
                mainUI.class
                ...Other Classes are here...
    run.bat
```